# Can´t get element by class name if class name is a number

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I tried to find an element by class name with the following code:

```
result.find_element_by_class_name("0")
```

`result` is an `WebElement` that contains the element I´m looking for. (I am sure about it)

The `html-code` is:

```
<tr class="0"></tr>
```

But if I do this I get the following Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given  selector 0 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>
> InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal class name was specified

There are other `WebElements` inside `result` which I can find via the class name (e.g. there is an element named `last` and if I try to get it, it works)

So, how can I find an element by class name, if the class name is a `Number`? (which is a string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name()` uses *CSS selectors* under the hood ([source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.47.1/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L700-L702)):

```
if by == By.ID:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = '[id="%s"]' % value
elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:  # < HERE
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = ".%s" % value
elif by == By.NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = '[name="%s"]' % value
```

And, the problem is, according to the [CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) "0" is not a valid class name, since a name must start with underscore (`_`), hyphen (`-`) or a letter ([relevant topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)). You can locate the element by XPath in this case:

```
result.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='0']")
```